# using operator delete an dynamic but still memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have write a code to calculate average of an area temperature in the map.

At start, the `initial()`will be invoked then `loadtempdata()` then `averagetemp()` and finally `cleanup()`.

And I have use a global pointer to point to a heap dynamic array in function so that it can be used in other funcion. Finally, I use the `delete[] table` to recycle the memory but the result indicate that I still have memory leak and I have found it long time and cannot find the reason.

Why is there still memory leak?

Thx in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
namespace TEST
{
    double *table = 0;
    const double *mtx = 0;
    int n = 0, m = 0;

    void LoadTempData(const double* matrix_row_major, int M, int N){
        table = new double [(M + 1) * (N + 1)];
        mtx = matrix_row_major;
        m = M;
        n = N;
        for(int i = 1; i < M + 1; i ++){
            for(int j = 1; j < N + 1; j ++){
                table[j + i * (N + 1)] = matrix_row_major[(j - 1) + (i - 1) * N]
                + table[j - 1 + i * (N + 1)]
                + table[j + (i - 1) * (N + 1)]
                - table[j - 1 + (i - 1) * (N + 1)];
            }
        }
    }
    double RegionAvgTemp(int y1, int x1, int y2, int x2){
        if(y1 == y2){
        return (table[x2 + 1 + (y2 + 1) * (n + 1)]
        - table[x2 + 1 + (y2 - 1 + 1) * (n + 1)]
        - table[x1 - 1 + 1 + (y1 + 1) * (n + 1)]
        + table[x1 - 1 + 1 + (y1 - 1 + 1) * (n + 1)]) / (x2 - x1 + 1);
        }
        else if(x1 == x2){
        return (table[x2 + 1 + (y2 + 1) * (n + 1)]
        - table[x1 + 1 + (y1 - 1 + 1) * (n + 1)]
        - table[x2 - 1 + 1 + (y2 + 1) * (n + 1)]
        + table[x1 - 1 + 1 + (y1 - 1 + 1) * (n + 1)]) / (y2 - y1 + 1);
        }
        else if ((y1 == y2) && (x1 == x2)){
            return mtx[x1 + y1 * n];
        }
        else{
        return (table[x2 + 1 + (y2 + 1) * (n + 1)]
        + table[x1 - 1 + 1 + (y1 - 1 + 1) * (n + 1)]
        - table[x2 + 1 + (y1 - 1 + 1) * (n + 1)]
        - table[x1 - 1 + 1 + (y2 + 1) * (n + 1)]) / ((y2 - y1 + 1) * (x2 - x1 + 1));
        }
        return 0;
    }


    void Init()
    {

    }

    void Cleanup()
    {
        delete[] table;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would suggest you use an `std::vector<double>` and avoid the problem altogether. There is no need to have to deal with this kind of issue in C++.

Comment: Why isn't this a `class` with a constructor and a destructor?

Comment: it has be sent to a online judge system to compete speed, that is its format.

Comment: a bit offtopic, but I don't believe the following `if` will ever work: `else if ((y1 == y2) && (x1 == x2))`;

Comment: oh, its precondition is x1 <= x2, y1 <= y2

Comment: And I question the usefulness of things like `y2 - 1 + 1`. Regarding your memory leak. WinDbg would probably help, but not as much as heeding the first comment in this list.

Comment: but is std::vector<double> will be faster than primitive tpye in new ?

Comment: have you run your program through something like valgrind?

Comment: I first hear it, I will try it now.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that you have a memory leak? Are you sure the Cleanup() function is ever invoked? What is this *result* you're talking of?

Comment: @Liang-Yu Pan, are you sure you do the following "steps" in the program: `Init(); LoadTempData(...); RegionAvgTemp(...); Cleanup();` and that's all? Maybe you do several `LoadTempData(...)` and only single `Cleanup()`?

Comment: Oh, it is the result that the system give me, the functionality and test data all are correct.

Comment: Oh, I finish it. Thx for everybody's help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your pre conditions the only cause for memory leaks I can think of is the following: multiple calls to `LoadTempData`. You should add the following code at the beginning of the `LoadTempData` function:

```
if (table != 0)
    Cleanup();
```

Otherwise 2 calls to `LoadTempData` will cause the first data pointer to be simply overwritten without actually deallocating it.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a chance that you, or the judge system calls LoadTempData more than once before Cleanup() is called?